# How do we find a lower bound on (P) without actually solving it?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

So, if we have $(P)$ min $\{ 4x_1 - x_2 : 3x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = -2, x_1 + x_2 - x_4 =2, x \ge 0 \}$ how to find the lower bound without actually doing it ?

Comment: please include what do you mean by "the" lower bound? if one has a lower bound, we can clearly further reduce it. You might like to include any ideas that you have in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x_{1,2}$ in terms of $x_{3,4}$.

$4x_1=x_3+x_4\\x_2=2-x_3/4+3x_4/4$

So $4x_1-x_2=5x_3/4+x_4/4-2$ which has minimum value $-2$ when $x_{3,4}=0$. Now check whether for $x_{3,4}=0$, we get $x_{1,2}\ge0$.